# Stylling Scrollbars

Tags: css

I am creating a div. For Overflow-y, I needs to customise scrollbars for every browser. I write my css as below, but it appears as default. Kindly suggest !!

```
#right_side {
float:right;
width:906px;
position:relative;
top:50px;
height:360px;
background:#F00;
scrollbar-base-color: #000000;
scrollbar-track-color: #c0c0c0;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #c0c0c0;
overflow: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

> jScrollPane is a cross-browser jQuery plugin by Kelvin Luck which
>   converts a browser's default scrollbars (on elements with a relevant
>   overflow property) into an HTML structure which can be easily skinned
>   with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Only WebKit borwsers and IE supoorts to change scrollbar apperance.

But you can use a jquery plugin named JScrollPane

Hope it helps